# Teradata - How to Check if User has "WITH GRANT" option?

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I check if a user has SELECT "WITH GRANT" option in Teradata? I know how to get a list of permissions using DBC.ROLEMEMBERS and DBC.ALLROLERIGHTS, just not seeing a way to check if "WITH GRANT" option is allowed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `GrantAuthority` only exists in `AllRightsV`, `UserGrantedRightsV` and `UserRightsV` for a simple reason:

```
5613 GRANT OPTION cannot be granted to a role.
Explanation: WITH GRANT OPTION can only be granted to users or databases.
Generated By: resname2 module.
For Whom: End User.
Remedy: Remove WITH GRANT OPTION and re-submit request.
```